Observable effects of modified Heisenberg uncertainty for fields
Suppose that a QFT has the following "same-time" commutation relations for two fields:
\begin{equation}
    \left[\hat{\psi}(t,\vec{x}),\hat{\Pi}(t,\vec{y})\right] = i\hbar\frac{1}{\pi\sqrt{\pi}\epsilon^{3}}e^{-\left(\frac{r_{x} - r_{y}}{\epsilon}\right)^{2}}
\end{equation}
Where $r_{x} = \sum_{i}^{3}x_{i}^{2}$ and similarly for $y$.
Apart from the violation of locality, would there be any physical observable that would get a dependency from the $\epsilon$ parameter, in the case of this modified uncertainty principle? Is there a possible experiment to probe the value of the $\epsilon$ parameter, for example in a QFT describing a self-interacting scalar field?
EDIT: What's interesting to me is if there is an experiment one can do to immediately rule out any positive value for $\epsilon$.

What problem is motivating this question?

Some context, background, and citations of relevant research citations are needed. For example, is this related to the generalized uncertainty principle, or modified uncertainty principles based on the Planck Length, such as discussed in "Quantum gravity and minimum length" or "The Uncertainty Principle and the Minimal Space–Time Length Element"?

it's not related to anything, it's just a question out of curiosity

It looks like you are course-graining the spatial degrees of freedom. The $\epsilon$ sets a scale at some point where experimental results would reveal this. My guess is that it will show up as a violation of Bjorken scaling.

Comment to the post (v5): Suppose that a QFT has the following "same-time" commutation relations for the field and conjugate momentum distributions.... Then it is by definition not the conjugate momentum.

Ok sorry I will call it the "Pi Function" how about that? Actually, the "Pi epsilon function" since I guess for every epsilon we have a different conjugate momentum? Can we stop fixating on names in here? Literally everybody with some QFT exposure will understand what Pi(t,y) is in the question, let's not play dumb come on

I edited the question @Qmechanic, is it ok now? You closed it right at the point when some people were answering it, instead of complaining about conventions

Even for very tiny values of $\epsilon$, as long as it is finite, this violates the converse of the spin-stats theorem, and because of that, it will also violate macro-locality. I don't think there is interest in physics hypotheses that violate SR on the macroscopic scale. Although this is not usually treated in QFT texts as-is, it is treated in high detail in the standard reference on the spin-stats theorem, and so the violated result is very well-known in the mainstream literature. You should have just read up.

in which way one would observe a violation in an experiment? for example for spin 1/2 particles, is it possible to rule out any positive value for epsilon?

You needed to tag the person if you want a reply. Yes, epsilon cannot be any finite positive value, because, again, it immediately implies a violation of macrolocality. That theorem is one of the strictest in QFT; after all, it is extremely rare that a requirement of large scale physics gets to imply that smaller scale physics has to also obey a simple relation.

@naturallyInconsistent yes but I asked what is an example of an experimental outcome that would immediately rule out positive values, like a concrete scenario
